# kafka direct stream and seekToEnd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

In my Spark job I initialize Kafka stream with `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`.

I read about `seekToEnd` method for `Consumer`. How can I apply it to the stream?

Answer (score 0):

spark-kafka transitively includes kafka-clients, so you're welcome to initialize the raw consumer instance on your own and seek it

Alternatively, if no consumer group exists, you would set `startingOffsets=latest` in your Spark config

note: Kafka Direct Stream API is deprecated as of Spark 2.4 and you should be using Structured Streaming instead